# How to position the custom tab in customer edit page in admin panel - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, custom, admin-panel, magento2.2

I created a custom tab in customer edit page in admin panel. It works perfectly, but I want to position the tab, so I tried to edit the **`customer_index_edit.xml`** file like below by adding:

```
<action method="addTabAfter">
    <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
</action>
```

but it's not working and throwing an error:

> [2017-10-09 05:56:42] main.CRITICAL: Invalid method vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Rewardpoints::addTabAfter

My **customer_index_edit.xml** file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
         <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Rewardpoints" name="customer_edit_tab_rewardpoints">
            <action method="addTabAfter">
                 <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
            </action>
         </block>   
    </referenceBlock> 
</body>
</page>
```

How to position the tab after **wishlist** tab in customer edit page in admin panel?

Comment: let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `after="wishlist"` in your custom link.

Your final new custom link code:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form">
     <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Rewardpoints" name="customer_edit_tab_rewardpoints" after="wishlist">
        <action method="setTabLabel">
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Your Tab Label</argument>
        </action>
     </block>   
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
What is <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tab/path</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Your Tab</argument>?

Comment: Check my updated answer